# Change the "Sign In" button color in ADFS v4.0 (Windows 2016 Server)

Tags: colors, css, windows-server

I've deployed **AD FS v4.0 (Windows 2016 Server)** and management wants a unified login page color scheme.  I've been working to try and change the color of the "*Sign In*" and "*Sign Out*" buttons on the login form page when my user's log on.  Is it possible to change the "*Sign In*" and "*Sign Out*" button color for **AD FS v4.0** (it doesn't use IIS any longer)?  I'm guessing it is somewhere in the CSS style sheet but I can't figure it out.  Anyone out there know where/how it can be done, if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change this at the css (bold):

input[type="submit"]:hover,span.submit:hover
{
    background: **rgb(111, 227, 126)**;
}

and

span.submit, input[type="submit"]
{
    border:none;
    background-color:**rgb(0, 171, 98)**;
    min-width:80px;
    width:auto;
    .......

Answer (score -1):

Create theme backup New-AdfsWebTheme -Name custom -SourceName default

Export bkp theme to c: \ adfs \ theme Export-AdfsWebTheme -Name default -DirectoryPath c: \ adfs \ theme

Edit the line to be informed in the post above

Upload the modified theme. Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName custom -StyleSheet @ {path = "c: \ adfs \ theme \ css \ style.css"}

Aticar modified theme Set-AdfsWebConfig -ActiveThemeName custom

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Posts on this site need to be made in English.

Comment: I replaced this with English from Google Translate, but it is still very hard to follow.